# IBM Cloud Security and Compliance Dashboard - scan function can't assess linux instances

Tags: security, ibm-cloud

I have been going through the tutorial/getting started for setup of the new IBM Cloud Security and Compliance Dashboard, to analyze and report on security/compliance for Cloud accounts. I've gotten to the point where I can run one of the canned profile validation "Scans" .. the one for "IBM Cloud Best Practices Controls 1.0" is working fine now, so at least basic credentials for the account are working. What it is now showing is validation results for the "Linux hardening profile" ... I'm sure it has something to do with inventory and key configuration, but I can't see from the documentation or general web searches, how to set it up for the individual linux instances in the account (either classic or ones in a VPC). One of the options on the support page was stack overflow, so I thought I would give it a shot. If anybody has a specific recommendation, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you installed the collector on the Linux instance already?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do the credential mapping.
Click on the lock icon in your scope

[Scope - Mapping credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whisk.png)

And map the IP address and select the appropriate credentials configured as below

[image: IP and credentials mapping]

Comment: thank you data_henrik , that was definitely one of the pieces missing. I've added this , with hopefully the appropriate conversion of openssh key format to PEM in the credential entry for on-prem. Still hasn't worked yet, but I'm one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I did not update properly the first image.Sorry about that. Please see the below image to see the credential mapping icon.
[Scope Credential Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClZpT.png)

Comment: could you remove one of the answers and focus on one?

Comment: Thanks for responses ... so it sounds like even though my virtual instance is within the cloud itself , and the same account ... in order to do the linux validation , I have to use the configuration for credentials that makes it "appear" that it is an "on-prem" system ... right ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone who provided info, guidance and hints that allowed me to get the linux validation scans working on virtual instances within my VPC (those in and out of stackoverlow) … I’ll try and list out here the key items that helped resolve in todays environment …

To do the system OS level validation scans (i.e. best practices for linux hardening) you need to consider your systems “onPrem” , even if they are classic infra or VPC infra , within the same cloud account that you have access to from SCC

For username/PEM credential type (SCC -> Configure -> Settings) , when you convert your SSH private key file to a PEM file  - you need to make sure that you do not have a passphrase on the new PEM format file you create (and then upload as part of the credential creation in SCC) … note: since private key files without passphrases are not best practice … once you have done the upload , securely  delete the temporary PEM private key file from your local system

Naturally make sure the public key that corresponds to the private key … is in the .ssh/authorized_keys file of the user that SCC will login as (based on the configuration in the SCC credential entry)

Configure/install the new collector, on a system in the same VLAN/subnet as the systems you want to scan/validate (i.e.  10.240.128.0/24). I'm told there are ways it can scan other vlans/subnets as long as routing is in place, but I have not explored this yet.

I ended up using CentOS 7 for my collectors, because I was running into a problem with repos and yum installation of docker

Install the nmap utility on the linux system where you will run the collector

Make sure docker-compose is installed and the docker service is actually started… before you run the initiate_collector.sh script

Configure collector as restricted, Discovery mode, Discovery-Enabled When you run the initiate_collector.sh script .. choose Y for nmap and specify interface (for me it was “eth0")

Setup a separate scope (from the one doing your general IBM Cloud Account validation) as OnPrem

Configure a new entry for “mapping credentials” in your new scope and specify an individual IP, multiple IPs or a range … “IP=” , “IP=<ipaddr1,ipadd2,ipaddrN>” or "IP=” (i.e. IP=10.240.128.4-10>)